# Faroo API using spaces as part of the query

Tags: api, search-engine

I know its a very primitive question, I have some problem with using [faroo](http://faroo.com) api.

The basic problem is that I can't search for (some) queries that contain spaces

These are a set of examples that works even though they contain spaces:

```
http://www.faroo.com/api?q=hello&s=1&l=en&src=web&key=<SecretKey>    (doesn't have space)
http://www.faroo.com/api?q=hello%20world&s=1&l=en&src=web&key=<SecretKey>   (has space)
```

on the first query I'm searching for **hello** and for the second query I searched for **hello world**.

However, As I move into phrases that are less popular I basically get empty result set.

for example:

```
http://www.faroo.com/api?q=nafas&s=1&l=en&src=web&key=<SecretKey>
http://www.faroo.com/api?q=nafas%20stackoverflow&s=1&l=en&src=web&key=<SecretKey>
```

for these two queries I end up getting empty results however if I search them in faroo.com I get the right results.

so Basically my question is that:

1. Am I not considering something here that should be/ shouldn't be there?
2. Could it be a bug within the API itself?

Comment: have the same issue, you got the solution?

Comment: @Name well, still waiting for them to get more popular hehe lol, meanwhile we just made our in house crawler :/

Comment: i got a answer from faroo. they mean if they didn't find any results for your query the return bing results, which they dont put in their api. this is the reason for the empty result

Comment: @Name sorry, I didn't explain why i wasn't working, I just said we have to wait for it to get popular ( basically an possible solution) lol